# audio tool development

Tags: audio

I'm in the need for some competent suggestions about where to start with audio tool development. I've been in graphics programming for several years now and thought it would be a refreshing experience to expand my knowledge in a completely other direction.
Where do you see a good starting point for a newbie like me? For the beginning, some lines of code producing cacophonous sounds would make me happy already. What audio API would you recommend when aiming for cross platform support? What do I've to consider generally?

I most likely missed to give you important information to make my intentions clear, so just ask!

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tool"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention any specific languages, but in any case I'd suggest trying out some higher level exploratory tools for analysis/synthesis first.  If you want to explore synthesis, oscillators, filters etc then you could try something like [SynthMaker](http://synthmaker.co.uk/index.html). If you want to experiment with audio analysis then try a tool such as [Marsyas](http://marsyas.info/).  If you want to deal with streaming audio and playlists then take a look at the [Echo Nest API](http://the.echonest.com/platform/).  Once you've explored these higher level tools then it'll give you a starting point to dive into algorithms.  Given that you have a background in graphics then much of the signal processing and filtering aspects should be familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics requires you know a lot about geometric projection, rendering, textures, etc.

Audio requires you know a lot about signal generators, filters, etc.  [I'm clearly not an expert].  But like the graphics stuff, reading a good book the basics of signal processing would probably help you a lot.   Also, like graphics, getting somebody else's tool is pretty good and playing with to understand what they think the problem is and what kinds of things they can do makes sense.

Then, and only then, would I attempt to code something.

Answer (score 0):

A good place do discuss audio processing and programming is the [dsp and plugin development forum](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=33) at the KVR audio website. Virtual instruments and plugins are a great way to experiment with audio programming, because the audio i/o is generally handled by host software. This would let you get making noise quickly. The skills learnt making plugins transfer to other audio applications well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're very comfortable with c I think the best place to start would be C Sounds http://www.csounds.com/   It's a cross platform audio processing environment suitable for any number of audio tasks including algorithmic composition.

Answer (score 0):

[Making Audio Plugins](http://www.martin-finke.de/blog/tags/making_audio_plugins.html) gives a very gentle start without too much DSP math.

The tutorials start from the very beginning and show how to create a synthesizer. The framework used is cross-platform (Win/Mac) and compiles to a standalone application as well as all major plugin formats.

Answer (score -1):

In case someone new stumbles upon this question and likes to use Python, try using [Nsound](http://nsound.sourceforge.net/users_guide/intro/getting_started.html):

```
$ pip install nsound
```

An intro video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4uLvl68PtI).

Answer (score -1):

You don't mention a language. I have been doing audio development in Java, making use of core language functions and javax.sound.sampled library. For "real world" tools, probably C is a bit better. But there are uses in Java, e.g., gaming. If you'd like to see what a bit of what I've done, there are two links to check out:

[home site web apps](http://adonax.com/main/musicapps.htm)

[demos for audio library work-in-progress](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/audio-library-demos/36682/msg/348918/view.html#msg348918)

This is mostly if you want to roll your own. There is a LOT you can do without getting into heavy duty DSP like filters. You can still play with effects like echo, chorus, flanging, FM synthesis, wave-table synthesis, all sorts of mixing.

If you want to use libraries, I think good ones to try are Processing, PD, CSound, a couple more I'm having trouble remembering.

Also, maybe check out [Praxis-live](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/audio-library-demos/36682/msg/348918/view.html#msg348918) for live-coding audio.